# create multi column (icon and text) from database

Tags: datatool

i create pdf file from my data file (see image)

Now i want to create multi column with icon and number (get from data file)

logo | logo | logo number 1 | number 2 | number 3

logo | logo | logo number 4 | number 5 | number 6

my code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,oneside,14pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,,left=0.5cm,right=1cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,hooks}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{setspace}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{filedataThiSinh}{filedataThiSinh.tex}

\usepackage{fix-cm}    
\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{50}{60}}
\makeatother    
\newcommand{\printNoiThiCoding}[1]{%
 \par
 \DTLforeach*
 [\DTLiseq{\NoiThiCoding}{#1}]%
 {filedata}% Database
 {\NoiThiCoding=Noi Thi,\STTCoding=STT}{%



 \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Logo/VuaHieuSuat.jpg} \newline
 Number: {\fontsize{0.5cm}{0.5cm}\selectfont \STTCoding}

 } 
  } %End cua Node
 
 \newpage


\begin{document}



%\DTLdisplaydb{filedataThiSinh}
%\newpage
\printNoiThiCoding{NT}


\end{document}
```

[image]

File data:

```
STT|So Bao Danh | STT

1|TNMT\_254|Name 1|11

2|TNMT\_405|Name 2|11
```

Comment: Without knowing what is inside the file `filedataThiSinh.tex`, it is hard to grasp what you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: @JasperHabicht just updated. thank you

Comment: It is still very hard for me to understand what exactly you want your code to do. With the data you provided, I get the following error when compiling the code: `Package datatool Error: Can't add entry with ID 'STT' to current row of database 'filedataThiSinh'.` Apart from that, you should not load packages twice in your preamble, and it would be nice if you could help us understand your code better by removing those packages from your code that are not needed for your example here.